# send really large files to server via flash/air application

Tags: actionscript-3, networking, file-upload, air

i've been searching for the answers for a day or two and i still don't know how to approach this problem.

i want to make an application to upload really large files to a server. i've decided to go for the adobe air because i thought it would be less restricting than flash, anyways, i am using actionscript3.

if i wanted to use a regular file uploading class i meet a server restriction of max file size (i tried working with php).

i googled something about "chunked fileupload" where i send small amounts of 64bit encoded data to a server via urlloader class and then merge them in php. this, however, creates a massive extra upload size overhead (because of the 64bit encoded data).

another idea i read about is to use a "socket connection" send a direct tcp stream. however, i have absolutely no idea how do sockets work and what should i use as a server. i tried using some simple php socket example code found online but i didn't really understand how would i use this for fileupload and flash didn't want to connect to it anyways. maybe someone could enlighten me on that?

or maybe someone has a better experience in the chunked fileupload method? is there an already existing library for handling large fileuploads in actionscript?

really **ANY** advice would be appreciated, i feel kind of lost in my quest.

i **do** have control over the server to some extent maybe i will convince sysadmins to install some service for me.

Comment: What is a 'really large' file? 500 MB? 50GB?

Comment: Have you tried [increasing the max upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) on your server?

Comment: a 'really large file' is, for example, 10 gb.
and icnreasing max upload file size on server is not an option. it has to be either streamed or chunked